# How to make a patch for one tag with Git?

Tags: git, release

We use git to manage our code, and just create one tag when release new version. So if we

find bugs after we release and hava made some new changes, how to deal with case ?

BTW: we do not use mutil branch because we would like to make process easy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This situation is part of the reason branches exist, so I suspect that in the long run you're just making things harder for yourself by avoiding branches. I suppose you could do something like this, though:

- Checkout the release tag.
- Make your bugfix, commit, re-tag and release the fix.
- Rebase master off of your new tag.

This will insert your fix in the timeline (by avoiding branches you've linearized your commit graph) immediately after the release.

### Update

As @cdhowie points out in the comments, "this approach will not work seamlessly if more than one developer has the repo cloned, since it will alter history and require a forced push". See the section of the `git-rebase` man page tilted "Recovering from Upstream Rebase" where it says:

> Rebasing (or any other form of rewriting) a branch that others have
>          based work on is a bad idea: anyone downstream of it is forced to
>          manually fix their history. This section explains how to do the fix
>          from the downstream’s point of view. The real fix, however, would be to
>          avoid rebasing the upstream in the first place.

So in other words, you *could* go with a rebasing strategy and keep your history linear, but you're probably actually creating more work for yourself that way. Having a separate branch for each release is the standard practice for good reason.

Comment: The history will not be linear after this operation; the history will branch implicitly.

Comment: @cdhowie Are you referring to the temporary branch before the rebase, the set of (now orphaned) commits between the tag and master, or something else?

Comment: Haha, actually I must've been really sleepy or something; I missed the rebase step.  Yes, the history will be linear after this.  But you should point out in your answer that this approach will not work seamlessly if more than one developer has the repo cloned, since it will alter history and require a forced push.

Comment: @cdhowie You're absolutely right. I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use a per-release branch that you can commit fixes to.  This is the easiest way to manage releases.

... And if you don't want to use the branching feature of Git, why aren't you using something with a GUI, like Subversion instead?  If simplicity of your VCS is a concern, Git is the wrong choice.  If awesome branching features are a concern, Git is the perfect choice.